# О хранение изображение в Базе Данных MySql

Tags: mysql, веб-программирование, изображения, bitmap, mobile-development

Есть рекламный вестник. Много жалоб приходит о том что изображения долго загружается.При этом я их как только не сжимаю в концу получаю 300-500x300-500. Есть конкурирующее приложения у них загружается изображения моментально. Думаю добиться этого можно с помощью хранение изображения в базе данных ввиде строки base64. Как вы оцените такой подход? Какие минусы и чего бояться при таком подходе? Может у вас есть предложения лучше?

Comment: 1. Для начала, я бы на вашем месте проверил, почему оно грузится долго. 2. А где вы его сейчас храните? Если на диске, то скорости доставки изображение на веб-сервер вам не добавит, если вы положите его в БД.

Comment: Вижу только минусы, боятся стоит того что у вас еще и страница будет грузится медленно а не только картинки

Comment: @Axenow долго грузится из за плохого интернета. При нормальном все ок. Сейчас храниться культурно на хостинге. Мне нужно улучшить время доставки из веб сервера

Comment: @user8978194 Тогда вам хранение данных в БД не поможет. Как это ускорит доставку контента до клиента?

Comment: @Axenow а что можете посоветовать чтобы ускорит доставку контента до клиента? У конкурентова же с таким инет получилось

Comment: @user8978194 Так я не знаю как ваше приложения работает, откуда и как вы берете данные, как и что вы отдаете клиенту и т.д. Тут анализировать надо. )

Comment: @Axenow спасибо за диалог. Перехотел хранить изображения в бд. За собой тянет еще больше проблем

Comment: зачем base64? храните как есть - бинарные данные самой фотки. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014578/storing-images-in-mysql

Comment: @Lexx918 и чем это поможет? почему никто не пишет что так делать не нужно? **не нужно хранить файлы в БД**.

Comment: А что, у конкурентов изображения хранятся на том же сервере, что и вы? Может у них вообще CDN для этих целей, нет?